# What is a heat source and heat sink in relation to thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics

Honestly, I have exams in two weeks and this is something I missed. What is a heat source and heat sink and how do they interact? I get that a heat sink is for dissipating heat, and it's obvious that a heat source is the source of heat but how do they interact?

Comment: What does your textbook say about them that confuses you?

Comment: I don't have a textbook, just my notes.

Comment: Wow, this got a lot of views...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thermal reservoir, or thermal bath is a thermodynamic system with a heat capacity that is large enough that when it is in thermal contact with another system of interest or its environment, its temperature remains effectively constant.It is an effectively infinite pool of thermal energy at a given, constant temperature. As mentioned above, but important to stress, the temperature of the reservoir does not change when heat is added or extracted because of the infinite heat capacity. As it can act as a source and sink of heat, it is often also referred to as a heat reservoir or heat bath. And in the context of a thermodynamic cycle, a heat source and a heat sink.